# Matlab Make Array Fit for Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I have two equal sized arrays in matlab that I would like to turn into a map (first array keys second array value).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do dictionaries in MATLAB is using [map containers](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html).

You create them as

```
mapObj = containers.Map({key1, key2, ...}, {val1, val2, ...});
```

I am assuming that your equal sized arrays are actually cell-arrays, otherwise use `mat2cell`